# What are the steps to install Natron on Ubuntu?

Tags: binary, compositing

At first I tried to install from the official sources, 
Natron was not there, so I searched for a PPA and I did not find Natron.

Now I read something about binaries and an install script, it did not work.

Please help me with the steps to install Natron.

Comment: " it did not work." is not acceptable for a question. We need the actual error on the actual instructions you used and the notice you get where you got stuck. I remove the "mint" tag: we only support official versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: ok, I read a description of installing the binaries. It was like this:   1) download the .tar.gz binary from the developer 2) extract it with your file browser 3) sudo apt-get libegl1-mesa 4) cd ~/Downloads/Natronxxx  5) ./install   . At step 4 it did not work because the thing that got unpacked into the ~/Downloads folder was not a folder itself but a file, so i could not enter it in order to run the install-script in 5) ....

Comment: Hey i did not vote as "off topic" :(

Comment: Why is this question off-topic?

Comment: @A.B. I was wondering the same. See the edit ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download the Linux package from the Natron website.
2. Extract the downloaded package.
3. Install the required package to run the Natron installation script :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libegl1-mesa
   ```
4. Install Natron :

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/Natron-*
   sudo ./Install.sh
   ```

Natron should now be available in your Dash. You can also lauch it from a terminal by running `natron`.

Comment: step 2b: read the readme ;-)

Comment: I downloaded the file Natron_Linux_x86-64bits_v1.2.1.tar.gz into ~/Downloads,  extracted it using the file browser into ~/Downloads/Natron_Linux_x86-64bits_v1.2.1.   Then, I tried to enter Natron_Linux_x86-64bits_v1.2.1.  in order to run the install script but I could not enter it , because it turned out to be a file and not a folder after I did    ls -l Natron_Linux_x86-64bits_v1.2.1

Comment: Indeed my bad, simply double click on it to install.

Comment: great, it really works

Comment: The website is now at https://natrongithub.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

I found other way to install Natron, more easy, from Deepin Linux Package

Here you chose your architecture 32 or 64 bits:

http://packages.deepin.com/deepin/pool/main/n/natron/

[image: Natron in deepin linux package]

I install it in UbuntuStudio 16.04 64bits.

All dependences are satisfied.

Here a screenshot:

[image: Natron 2016]

This program are only in english.

Say to me whatever about this you find

Answer (score 0):

Last days, I've worked through the various pieces of information and the old packages still out there, and combined that with the newest sources from Github (Natron 2.3.15 RC14).

See my PPA
https://launchpad.net/~ichthyo/+archive/ubuntu/natron